# GWT : CellTree with Editor Framework

Tags: java, gwt

I'm refactoring my GWT App with the framework Editor.

I'm stuck with a view that contains a CellTree widget. I don't see how to wrap my ***CustomTreeViewModel*** with the **editor Framework**. 
Maybe I need to subclass the CellTree class?

**Precision :**
Here is my data structure in the CellTree :

rootLevel is null

ZoneProxy :

```
ZoneProxy parent;
List<ZoneProxy> childs;
List<PointProxy> points;
```

So I can have this :

```
|_ Zone 1
|  |_Zone 1.1
|  |_Zone 1.2
|     |_Point 1
|     |_Point 2
|_ Zone 2
.
.
.
```

I get the CellTree working without the EditorFramework, using two hashMaps :

```
private Map<ZoneProxy,ListDataProvider<ZoneProxy>> treeListDataZones;
private Map<ZoneProxy,ListDataProvider<PointProxy>> treeListDataPoints;
```

When a user clicks on a a Point in the tree, I have a right panel that should show the details of the point clicked.

I get the CellTree fills datas with the EditorFramework, but I make the CustomTreeViewModel of the CellTree implementing LeafValueEditor. I don't see how to go deeper with Editors. (I don't know wich Sub Editors I have to create with my data structure)

I think I'm missing something with the EditorFramework, I gonna read the Google DevGuide again.

I don't find any examples using Celltree with the Framework Editor. If someone has a good example, it will help me a lot. :)

Thanks

Comment: I found an adapter that adapts ListDataProvider to a ListEditor. I will see if it works, here is the link of the adapters : [Adapter Link](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmarkmail.org%2Fdownload.xqy%3Fid%3Dbpi2odbvilsvfm4v%26number%3D2&ei=2GYMU5SvF4TQ0QWPzgE&usg=AFQjCNGwIK9YiRLEuu8onO1_qhDeTqtV1Q&sig2=H3JUG62mAX1j8Ao91s8C4A&bvm=bv.61725948,d.d2k)

Comment: I m trying to use a CompositeEditor build like this : 
CompositeEditor<List<ZoneProxy>,List<PointProxy>,ListEditor<PointProxy,PointContentEditor>>. 

Is it a good idea? 
I gonna check the ListEditor code, it's a CompositeEditor<T,T,C>. But mine is Composite<T,List<U>,ListEditor<U,C>>... It's gonna be complex. :s

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you. Here is the sample code with some modification in actual code from [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/cellview/CellTreeExample.java?r=8944). Double click on text item to edit it.

```
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.EditTextCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.TreeViewModel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class GWTTestProject implements EntryPoint {
    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        // Create a model for the tree.
        TreeViewModel model = new CustomTreeModel();

        /*
         * Create the tree using the model. We specify the default value of the
         * hidden root node as "Item 1".
         */
        CellTree tree = new CellTree(model, "Item 1");

        // Add the tree to the root layout panel.
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tree);

    }

    /**
     * The model that defines the nodes in the tree.
     */
    private static class CustomTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {

      /**
       * Get the {@link NodeInfo} that provides the children of the specified
       * value.
       */
      public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
        /*
         * Create some data in a data provider. Use the parent value as a prefix
         * for the next level.
         */
        ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          dataProvider.getList().add(value + "." + String.valueOf(i));
        }

        EditTextCell textCell=new EditTextCell();
        // Return a node info that pairs the data with a cell.
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, textCell);
      }

      /**
       * Check if the specified value represents a leaf node. Leaf nodes cannot be
       * opened.
       */
      public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
        // The maximum length of a value is ten characters.
        return value.toString().length() > 10;
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx @Braj for your answer, but I get this part.
What I'm looking for is to wrap the CellTree with the [Editor Framework](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html).
I found a solution for now but it's not complete :
I implement LeafValueEditor<List<CellTreeItem>> on the CustomCellTree, so I can put datas in the CellTree.
I need to go deeper in hierarchy but I m stuck.
I will complete my Question. Thx again Braj :)